# Water propulsion: Use air and rigid form to make waves feasible or not?

Tags: fluid-statics

I had an idea that if you took a piece of material shaped like corrugated steel and positioned it such that the runs were horizontally oriented, attached it to the back of a water craft to span the width, angled the top of it at a tilt forward away from craft and at the bottom direct pressurized air up against it.

The idea is that since air bubbles rise in water, the tilt of the corrugated shaped material would force the bubbles to rise along the profile of the material and would move in an s pattern until finally reaching the surface of the water. The corrugated material would have to have a smaller span from the bottom and a larger span at the top so the bubbles travel upwards and outwards. To prevent the air bubbles from blowing out the sides a flange would have to be made to steer the path of the air to go up along the runs and not out the sides and up.

The theory is that the air rises and displaces space between the corrugated shaped form and water that creates a wave pattern as the water fills in and pushes out.

Just a thot

Comment: Probably it could work, but a drawing would help a lot.

Comment: this should go to engineering https://engineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mechanical-engineering